# Angular 8: "ReferenceError: global is not defined" When i'm trying to connect client application with my ethereum blckchain

Tags: angular, typescript, ethereum, solidity

I'm tyring to set my web3 provider with an injection token web3.ts which is imported by the app.component.ts and used into async ngOnInit().

I've already tried:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/https-medium-com-alexanddanik-ethereum-dapp-with-angular-angular-material-and-ngrx-f2c91435871b
It shows me the same error. 
I've also tried:
https://www.udemy.com/course/blockchain-ninja-develop-ethereum-dapp-with-angular/
Of course, it shows me the same error.

web3.ts:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import Web3 from 'web3';

export const WEB3 = new InjectionToken<Web3>('web3', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => {
    try {
      const provider = ('ethereum' in window) ? window['ethereum'] : Web3.givenProvider;
      return new Web3(provider);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying Mist or MetaMask!');
    }
  }
});
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { WEB3 } from './web3';
import Web3 from 'web3';

constructor(@Inject(WEB3) private web3: Web3) { }

async ngOnInit() {
    if ('enable' in this.web3.currentProvider) {
        await this.web3.currentProvider;
    }
    const accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts);
}
```

--- The Console Error ---

```
    capability.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
        at Object../node_modules/stream-http/lib/capability.js (capability.js:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
        at Object../node_modules/stream-http/lib/request.js (request.js:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
        at Object../node_modules/stream-http/index.js (index.js:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
        at Object../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js (xml-http-request.js:21)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
        at Object../node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/index.js (index.js:6)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I used the `web3` keyword, I got the same error and after going through some articles I got the answer.

In the file `polyfill.js` located inside `src` add the code snippet.

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
global.process = require('process');
```

At first you can try adding only the first line of the code, that most probably resolves the global error of the window `global is not defined`.

I added other lines of code because after the global error was resolved, a new error `buffer is not defined` is most likely to occur.

After you add the 2nd line to resolve this error, a new error relating to process will be there `process is not defined`.

`Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` after those errors.

But for me, this code did all the job.

More info on:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-386154063

Answer (score 0):

I think you should connect to the provider like this

```
  if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
      this.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!');
      Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send;
      this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
    }
```